# Yii2 link and form action always back to 'localhost' (wrong base url)

Tags: php, yii2

I've error on `yii2` after I upgrade the os to el capitan. My project root is `localhost/~robbyprawira/myproject/`.

I create a link ,for example `<a href="/home">link</a>` .and when I click that link on browser it will go to `localhost/home`. it should be  `localhost/~robbyprawira/myproject/home`

it happen to form action too.`<form action="/admin/update"></form>` .when I click the submit button,it will go to `localhost/admin/update`. should be `localhost/~robbyprawira/myproject/admin/update`

Anyone can help me fix this problem? thank you

```
<?php 
   use yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm;
   use yii\helpers\Html;
   use yii\helpers\Url; 
 ?> 

 <?php 
      $form = ActiveForm::begin(['action' => Url::to('/admin/update')]); 
   ?>
   <?= $form->field($model, 'admin_email', ['inputOptions' => ['title' => Yii::t('myproject/update','Email')]]) ?> 
   <?= Html::submitButton(Yii::t('myproject/update', 'Update'), ['class' => 'btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block']) ?> 
  <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

Comment: please provide your real yii2 / php code and not a summry so i can try to suggest the right solution..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yii2 give you a lot of components for this situation without using direct code so you can

for the link the proper way is use  URL helper

```
use yii\helpers\Url;

    <a href="<?= Url::to('LINK')?>">
```

for the ancor tag you can use  html Helper

```
  use yii\helpers\Html;

<?= Html::a('Home', ['home'], ) ?>
```

for the form you can use active Form

```
$form = ActiveForm::begin([
  'id' => 'login-form',
  'options' => ['class' => 'form-horizontal'],
  'action' => Url::to(['/admin/update']),
 ]) ?>
......

<?php ActiveForm::end() ?>
```

Comment: Try enclose between [] alis use the array notation ['admin/update'  ] for url

Comment: ah..thank you..works good for the link ,but need to remove '/' on the form action => admin/update .thank you...

Comment: do you have more suggestion?because i need to update many code for every link and form action in my project..

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use the following functions to make URLs:

For both at the top of the file:

```
use yii\helpers\Url;
```

1. Backend:

   `Url::to(Yii::getAlias('@web') . '/admin/update', true);`
2. Frontend

   `Url::to(Yii::getAlias('@web') . '/home', true);`

Does it work for you?